# Getting C indent options to work in .java files

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc`, I have the following line (twice!)

```
set cino=>2
```

This works well for all the indentation (two spaces) I want to do.  If I open up a `.c` file, the indentation works beautifully.

I also want the same indent options in my `.java` files, but when I open one of those, it automatically sets the indent to eight spaces.  I find myself having to type `:set cino=>2` whenever I open a `.java` file.

I thought at first that this might be because of the following:

> `indentexpr` - ... When this option is not empty, it overrules the `'cindent'` and `'smartindent'` indenting.

However, I opened up a `.java` file and typed `:set inde=`, and it didn't set the indenting back to the `cino=>2` that I have set in my `.vimrc`.  How can I fix this?

**Update:** I ran `:set` in  a `.java` file and, sure enough, `indentexpr` was not set.  However, `cinoptions` was set to `j1`, not to `>2`.  It's possible that some of the `j1` features are useful, but I would like indenting to be 2 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Piecing a few things together, I figured out the solution.

The problem, as I noticed, is not in the `indentexpr` variable, but in the `cinoptions` variable.  Creating a new file called `~\.vim\options\java.vim` containing the single line

```
set cino=>2
```

does it immediately.

Comment: Did you figure out what plugin or vim settings was setting the j1 option?

Comment: @Kelsin - It was so long ago, I can't remember.  I think it was the global `java.vim` file in the Vim folder that was setting j1.

Comment: @Kelsin It is in the default java indent file `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/java.vim` for me